# cURL , get redirect url to a variable

Tags: php, curl, redirect

I'm using curl to fill a form. After completion of the post the other script which handles the form is redirecting to another URL. I want to get this redirect URL into a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the destination URL using cURL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439040/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-using-curl)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You would use

```
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
```

And parse the headers for the `location` header

Comment: No problem, using the post fields will send the data and then server would redirect and as the data is outputted as the responses, curl will pick that up so then the location header should be there.

Answer (score 49):

Easy way to find the redirected url (if you don't want to know in advance)

```
$last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Comment: It is `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL`

Comment: I don't find CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: But I find it here http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php !!! CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL is added to 5.3.7 - but not documented. But from the source I assume that this is the (first) redirect url value in case curl call is not using auto redirect. So we would know what is next url in case we would have enabled the redirect.Thank you @Sparky for forcing me dig.

Comment: `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` works for me. `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL` doesn't return anything, maybe I'm just doing something wrong =/

Comment: CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL returns current (requested) page for me. There are no redirect (Location:) url in curl_info results. It seems, to parse headers is the best practice...

Comment: CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL gives the final url, if no redirection happened it will give the same URL as you requested. (Make sure you are allowing redirection in curl opts)

Comment: With the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option disabled: redirect URL found in the last transaction, that should be requested manually next. With the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option enabled: this is empty. The redirect URL in this case is available in CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL

Comment: It seems the redirect URL field isn't being filled for HTTP 201 Created responses.

Comment: `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL` get the URL a redirect would go to (on 301 or 302 response). `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` - get the last used URL (on 200 response).

Answer (score 8):

Here I get the resource http headers then I parse the headers out into an array $retVal. I got the code for parsing the headers from here (http://www.bhootnath.in/blog/2010/10/parse-http-headers-in-php/) You could also use http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-parse-headers.php if you have (PECL pecl_http >= 0.10.0)

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        $timeout = 0;
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        // Getting binary data
        $header = curl_exec($ch);
        $retVal = array();
        $fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
        foreach( $fields as $field ) {
            if( preg_match('/([^:]+): (.+)/m', $field, $match) ) {
                $match[1] = preg_replace('/(?<=^|[\x09\x20\x2D])./e', 'strtoupper("\0")', strtolower(trim($match[1])));
                if( isset($retVal[$match[1]]) ) {
                    $retVal[$match[1]] = array($retVal[$match[1]], $match[2]);
                } else {
                    $retVal[$match[1]] = trim($match[2]);
                }
            }
        }
//here is the header info parsed out
echo '<pre>';
print_r($retVal);
echo '</pre>';
//here is the redirect
if (isset($retVal['Location'])){
     echo $retVal['Location'];
} else {
     //keep in mind that if it is a direct link to the image the location header will be missing
     echo $_GET[$urlKey];
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I've tried this parsing code and it does not work, i was thrown several errors on the "explode()" part re: to converting an array to a string

Comment: in `preg_replace` **`/e modifier is deprecated`** can anybody update this answer?

Comment: found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17027154/725306) helpful with less line of code and complexity in regular expression

Answer (score 3):

You may want to set the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to true.

Or set the CURLOPT_HEADER to true and then use regexp to get the Location header.

Comment: Also take note of php safe mode with this, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#95027

Answer (score 1):

#### Hi. There is a new easy way.

##### If the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option is disabled (You are not being redirected automatically)

You can use `CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL`: **redirect URL found in the last transaction**

```
$redirect_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
```

---

###### Or if the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option is enabled (Auto redirect)

You can use `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL`: last requested URL (in this case is the last redirect URL)

```
$redirect_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, thank me later

```
           $fp = fopen($public_path . '/' . $file_name, 'wb');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); 
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            $redirect_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); 
            //if you are downloading large file, you can now get its exetension from $redirect_url
```