# Get Url Response Using Php ( Curl )

Tags: php, curl

I have a URL `http://www.example.com?auth_key=VVAf3spUN3ZETRH0kVPg1`, when I open this URL normally or if do header location with php it redirects me to the same URL but with one more `$_GET` value appended to it which become

`http://www.example.com?auth_key=VVAf3spUN3ZETRH0kVPg1&&auth_token=OTdZN36QbPNo`, and then I access it's value using `$_GET['auth_token']`.

Is there any way to make a request to the first URL using cURL or any other method in PHP and then get the `$_GET['auth_token']` value as a response.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with curl yet? What does it return if not the redirected url? (Also: show your current code.)

Comment: You need to elaborate a bit more. Is the auth script yours? Does it depend on a session cookie etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cURL , get redirect url to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062819/curl-get-redirect-url-to-a-variable)

Comment: auth script belongs to a third party eCommerce website, it has nothing to do with cookies or sessions. Once i make a request it return me to same URL with one more $_GET param appended that i can use to retrieve items from their site.

Answer (score 0):

Using cURL with `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`, you could set [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to true, but not if `safe_mode` or `open_basedir` is enabled. On the same manual page you can find a [function](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#102121) to overcome this if needed, though. With `CURLOPT_HEADER` you should see the redirection header `Location: newURL` in the output string. You can extract your parameter from that, e.g. like this:

```
list($dummy, $location) = explode(':', $location_line, 2);
$parts = parse_url(trim($location));
if (isset($parts['query'])) {
   parse_str($parts['query'], $param_map);
   if (isset($param_map['auth_token'])) {
      ...
```

Comment: if you wont mind can you show a little example... though i am trying from my side too

Comment: @AmanVirk: there is plenty of examples in the manual. CURL is not a difficult subject. Setup your test and tweak it until it works.