# Rcurl not working with redirect

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cURL , get redirect url to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062819/curl-get-redirect-url-to-a-variable)

I am trying to plot a sequence logo using Rcurl and WebLogo at http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/logo.cgi

```
url = 'http://weblogo.berkeley.edu/logo.cgi'
result = postForm(url, "sequence"='HQDTQRRTSMGGTQQ', .cgifields = 'sequence', style="post")
```

I have tried this, but it just returns the html of the filled form (i.e. its not being submitted). When I looked into the timeline of a submit, I saw that the image generated is through a redirect. Any idea how I can get to that image?

Also: what is the point of .cgifields? its in many of the examples but what is its purpose?

Comment: No, not possible duplicate. I am using Rcurl, not curl.