# Regex and preg_replace

Tags: regex, preg-match

What does this line mean:

```
$fields = explode("\r\n", preg_replace('/\x0D\x0A[\x09\x20]+/', ' ', $header));
```

I got it from this answer [cURL , get redirect url to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062819/curl-get-redirect-url-to-a-variable/4243667#4243667)

Answer (score 1):

The `preg_replace` will unfold email [header lines that are split across multiple lines](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2.3). Then the `explode` call will split the resulting string into an array with one header line per array cell.

For example, the string:

```
Subject: This is a long subject
    line split across
  multiple lines
From: user@example.com
```

will be transformed by `preg_replace` into:

```
Subject: This is a long subject line split across multiple lines
From: user@example.com
```

and the following `explode` will give you:

```
Array(
    [0] => 'Subject: This is a long subject line split across multiple lines',
    [1] => 'From: user@example.com'
)
```