# Capture a custom URI after submission

Tags: javascript, php, curl, automation, uri

I am automating filling out a form.

The form redirects to a custom URI scheme `person-account` based upon the credentials entered.

I now have a PHP page that uses cURL to load up the form and displays the output.

The page has a **Captcha** on it. I have javascript pre-filling out my credentials, so all I  have to do is solve the captcha to continue.

But I need to capture the custom URI scheme `person-account` redirect AFTER the form is submitted so that I can continue automation once I am in.

The URI contains an **AuthenticationToken** I want to store in a database. (Which is the reason I have loaded the page in PHP using cURL.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
            CURLOPT_VERBOSE => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE
        ));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
echo $output;
//DO SOME JAVA STUFF TO FILL OUT THE FORM
curl_close($ch);
```

In the past I have used  the below snippet to retrieve header info:

```
//After calling a different cURL

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$header = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
```

*How do I capture that redirect URI from inside my PHP page after I submit the form and capture the URI?*

Do I even need use cURL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cURL , get redirect url to a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062819/curl-get-redirect-url-to-a-variable)

Comment: You can get URL like this $last_url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);