# PHP cURL: Get target of redirect, without following it

Tags: php, curl

The curl_getinfo function returns a lot of metadata about the result of an HTTP request.  However, for some reason it doesn't include the bit of information I want at the moment, which is the target URL if the request returns an HTTP redirection code.

I'm not using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION because I want to handle specific redirect codes as special cases.

If cURL can follow redirects, why can't it tell me what they redirect to when it isn't following them?

Of course, I could set the CURLOPT_HEADER flag and pick out the Location header.  But is there a more efficient way?

Comment: My program actually uses the body, in those cases where the URL isn't a redirect.  So this wouldn't improve matters at all.  My query was basically about whether there's a method of extracting the Location header that saves the overhead of doing it in PHP code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439040/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-using-curl

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use it: (CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL)

```
$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
echo $info; // the redirect URL without following it
```

as you mentioned, disable the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option (before executing) and place my code after executing.

> CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL - With the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option
> disabled: redirect URL found in the last transaction, that should be
> requested manually next. With the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION option
> enabled: this is empty. The redirect URL in this case is available in
> CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL

[Refrence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in 4 steps:

Step 1. Initialise curl

```
curl_init($ch); //initialise the curl handle
//COOKIESESSION is optional, use if you want to keep cookies in memory
curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
```

Step 2. Get the headers for `$url`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); //specify your URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); //include headers in http data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false); //don't follow redirects
$http_data = curl_exec($ch); //hit the $url
$curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$headers = substr($http_data, 0, $curl_info['header_size']); //split out header
```

Step 3. Check if you have the correct response code

```
if (!($curl_info['http_code']>299 && $curl_info['http_code']<309)) {
  //return, echo, die, whatever you like
  return 'Error - http code'.$curl_info['http_code'].' received.';
}
```

Step 4. Parse the headers to get the new URL

```
preg_match("!\r\n(?:Location|URI): *(.*?) *\r\n!", $headers, $matches);
$url = $matches[1];
```

Once you have the new URL you can then repeat steps 2-4 as often as you like.

Answer (score 1):

`curl` doesn't seem to have a function or option to get the redirect target, it can be extracted using various techniques:

**From the response**:

Apache can respond with a HTML page in case of a 301 redirect (Doesn't seem to be the case with 302's).

If the response has a format similar to:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.xxx.yyy/zzz">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at www.xxx.yyy Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

You can extract the redirect URL using `DOMXPath`:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($urls as $url) {
    if(substr($url,0,4) == "http") {
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = @curl_exec($c);
        $status = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($c);
        $results[$i]['code'] = $status;
        $results[$i]['url'] = $url;

        if($status === 301) {
            $xml = new DOMDocument();
            $xml->loadHTML($result);
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
            $href = $xpath->query("//*[@href]")->item(0);
            $results[$i]['target'] = $href->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

**Using CURLOPT_NOBODY**

There is a faster way however, as @[gAMBOOKa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157837/gambooka) points out; Using `CURLOPT_NOBODY`. This approach just sends a `HEAD` request instead of `GET` (not downloading the actual content, so it should be faster and more efficient) and stores the response header.

Using a regex the target URL can be extracted from the header:

```
foreach($urls as $url) {
    if(substr($url,0,4) == "http") {
        $c = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
        curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        $result = @curl_exec($c);
        $status = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($c);
        $results[$i]['code'] = $status;
        $results[$i]['url'] = $url;

        if($status === 301 || $status === 302) {
            preg_match("@https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\-\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?@",$result,$m);
            $results[$i]['target'] = $m[0];
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No there is no more efficient way
Your can use CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER + [VariableStream](http://www.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php)
So.. you could write headers to variable and parse it

Comment: Seems overkill for my purposes ... maybe I'll just use a simple callback now I've managed to make sense of them.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem  and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);` was of any help.

So, I decided not to use `CURL` but `file_get_contents` instead:

```
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$data = str_replace("<meta http-equiv=\"Refresh\" content=\"0;","<meta",$data);
```

The last line helped me to block the redirection although the product is not a clean html code.

I parsed the data and could retrieve the redirection URL I wanted to get.

Comment: It looks to me as if the page on which you were trying to block redirection was using a meta-refresh, rather than an HTTP redirect.  The latter is what I am dealing with.