# Curl still redirecting after setting FOLLOWLOCATION to FALSE

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Here is my code:

```
$url='http://celebcrust.com/?p=15055';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,  TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,         TRUE);                 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);

$httpData = curl_exec($ch);
var_export($httpData);
```

This code as an [interactive demo on phpdiffle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/epg-xyz).

Why is it still redirecting? I'm trying to get the redirected to URL. I set `FOLLOWLOCATION` to `FALSE` but still.

Comment: What Is Your Question? Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Could you give an example of a URL where you see this behavior, and be a little more clear about what exactly is happening? "this code with this site - the following happens; changing this line, this other things happens. I would like XXX to happen. How do I do it?" Your current description is more confusing than you realize.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Curl, follow location but only get header of the new location?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129000/curl-follow-location-but-only-get-header-of-the-new-location)

Comment: @Floris I added a phpfiddle

Comment: The link @hakre gave appears to be very relevant. Did you look at it?

Comment: @Floris did you look at my fiddle? I didn't tell you that i put it in the question. im already using CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION as false. If you click run on the fiddle youll see it still redirects, but it prints out the header stuff first (and i dont see a string location but it does redirect there). I think it has something to do with running the command curl_exec. I really dont know.

Comment: @hakre Id like to recreate this question. It didn't start as defined as I made it, and from the start it had -2 votes. I don't think its getting any traction and I fixed the question to be more precise. I really would like to create it so I can get the traction it deserves now. I can set a bounty and wait a few days too.

Comment: Just edit it. Ping me here again and then we see if we can turn this into better. Ok?

Comment: Also as you wrote you do follow-location you will only get the headers returned of the last request in the chain, so the `Location: ...` header will be *never* in there. You understand why (now)? --- err my fault. reading helps :) perhaps there is no location header? can you share the URL, then I take a look what is so mysterious about this.

Comment: @hakre Here is the original URL: http://celebcrust.com/?p=15055 . As you can see it does a redirect. If you look at my fiddle I wrote you can see the entire execution. Ill be back in a few hours and ill work more on the question. Thanks.

Comment: Easy to say by having the link. There actually is no such header, you find that outlined in my answer below. No magic here.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here is how I do debug these things quickly (it's not working always, but for first try to hit the rubber on the road for more contact, this normally does it):

Requirements: Curl for the commandline (available probably for every computer system on earth, visit the homepage if you don't have it yet):

`-i` is to list headers as well (use `-I` for HEAD request if too much data comes) and then `-v` for verbose (shows what goes where):

```
$ curl -iv 'http://celebcrust.com/?p=15055'
* Adding handle: conn: 0xa50260
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0xa50260) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to celebcrust.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 70.32.78.224...
* Connected to celebcrust.com (70.32.78.224) port 80 (#0)
> GET /?p=15055 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: celebcrust.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2013 14:29:54 GMT
Date: Sat, 31 Aug 2013 14:29:54 GMT
* Server Apache is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache
Server: Apache
< X-Pingback: http://celebcrust.com/xmlrpc.php
X-Pingback: http://celebcrust.com/xmlrpc.php
< X-Powered-By: PleskLin
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
< Content-Length: 159
Content-Length: 159
< Connection: close
Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<
<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.celebgossip.com/2013/04/willie-nelson-celebrates-80th-birthday-stoned-and-auditi
oning-for-gandalf-39425/">
* Closing connection 0
```

As this shows the server does not send a `Location:` header so this totally explains that you don't see one.

Instead it sends HTML in the response body that is parsed by hypertext client (webbrowser) for a `Refresh:` HTTP-equivalent header value.

That is not the buisness of curl. You need to add a HTML parser and check for these, I suggest `DOMDocument` with it's `->loadHTML()` method.