# PHP get response for POST after redirect

Tags: php, curl, redirect

Hi I am using the following code to post some data to enter a raffle. After the site recieves the data it redirects the user to a URL.

How can I get the response from the request from the redirected URL. As at the moment I get no response at all?

How can I check if its a successful entry or not?

Comment: add CURLOPT_VERBOSE: ```$stderrh=tmpfile();
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>1,CURLOPT_STDERR=>$stderrh));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
/* https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76268 */
rewind($stderrh); 
$stderr=stream_get_contents($stderrh);
fclose($stderrh);
echo $stderr;
``` and show us the verbose log

Comment: @hanshenrik

i have edited the originial post and added the verbose log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to return the redirect URL by following this thread:

[Curl, follow location but only get header of the new location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129000/curl-follow-location-but-only-get-header-of-the-new-location)

I added the following to my script:

$redirect = curl_getinfo($ch)['redirect_url'];
echo $redirect;