# Show curl redirection but don't follow

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.site.com/check.php?id=1");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2) Gecko/20100115 Firefox/3.6 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)");
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $curlData;
```

the script on the remote site will perform a certain check, and according to the check results it redirect to a small 15x15 gif image.

At the moment I have `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1` which means it will follow the redirection to the gif and when I echo `$curlData` I get the binary code of the image which is not what I want.

Is it possible to have curl display where the script tries to redirect me without actually following the redirect? So I can tell to which gif image it redirect me to instead of echoing the gif content?

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091208/php-curl-get-target-of-redirect-without-following-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily! Don't set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, and then read the `Location` header from the response.

Edit: So, a bit more detail. The headers will be the lines of the response just after the status line, separated with `\r\n`. You'll need to break up these lines, and look for the line prefixed with `Location:`. This is a string parsing exercise - nothing terribly exciting or tricky. You can use `curl_getinfo` with the `CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE` flag to discover the total length of the header portion of the response.