# cURL returns empty output from valid url - no errors reported

Tags: php, curl

If you just enter the urls into the browser you can see that both work, cdon works even without javascript, have they blocked cURL somehow?

I'm trying to build a scraper to benifit legal movies online which would benifit them a whole lot, seems stupid blocking scrapers in general imho. Although I'm far from sure that's whats going on here! Might be just an error somewhere..

```
// Works
get_file1('http://sfanytime.com/sv-SE/Sokresultat/?field=all&q=The+Matrix', '/', 'sfanytime.html');

// Saves a blank 0 KB file
get_file1('http://downloads.cdon.com/index.phtml?action=search&search_terms=The+Matrix', '/', 'cdon.html');

function get_file1($file, $local_path, $newfilename) {
    $out = fopen($newfilename, 'wb');
    if ($out === FALSE) {
        return false;
    }      
    $ch = curl_init();             
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $file);                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_exec($ch);
    $error = curl_error($ch);
    if (strlen($error) > 0) {
            echo "<br>Error is : ". $error;
        return false;
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I tested your code it returned: bool(true) bool(true)

Comment: Remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);`

Comment: @Oyeme Okay good to know but that doesn't really explain why it doesn't actually save the webpage.. DaveRandom Done but it didn't change anything for me..

Answer (score 3):

You should change the line

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
```

...to...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

`CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` will cause a "silent fail" - which from what you say, is not what you want. I have replaced this with `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, because when I visit the second URL, I get redirected to a "choose your country" type page, which will be a response with an empty body - which is why you get an empty file.

There is no problem with your code as such, simply a problem with the way you handle the response from the second URL. You don't see an error because, technically, there wasn't one.

Comment: Thanks! Still becomes an empty file though.. even with that changed!

Comment: @OZZIE hmmm... works for me, can you update the question with your current code?

Comment: Can you send preffered language via cURL ?

Comment: It depends how the site is setup, I imagine it uses cookies. Hang on, let me have a play with it.

Comment: Hmm okay well I didn't solve it but at least now I get a response: "HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Thu, 01 Dec 2011 13:49:51 GMT Server: Apache Set-Cookie: cdon=s4XKhFniWFPlY; path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Location: flagpage.php X-Server: 1 Content-Length: 0 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 "

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` should prevent your from getting that - it should result in cURL following the redirect...

Comment: seems like that doesn't always work.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230002/show-curl-redirection-but-dont-follow .. anyway found that I can just add "country=..." to the url to avoid the problem ;P