# PHP/Javascript Get All Redirect's of an URL

Tags: javascript, php

If we have an URL say `firsturl.com` is redirected to `secondurl.com` to `thirdurl.com` to `fourthurl.com(Destination Url)`.

How can we display `secondurl.com,thirdurl.com` and `fourthurl.com` using JavaScript or PHP.

I am using PHP script `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);` to find out the destination URL,I also want to display second URL and third URL.

Comment: Hi! What have you tried so far?

Comment: function get_redirect_final_target($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init($url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1); // set referer on redirect
    curl_exec($ch);
    $target = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($target)
        return $target;
    return false;
}

Comment: @MadhanKumar why didn't you post as an answer? it's hard to read code that long in a comment.

Comment: @fpietka  I can able to get only final url,How can we get second url and third url

Comment: @MadhanKumar please add your code in the question itself, so it'll be more readable for everybody.

Comment: @MadhanKumar see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7230002/show-curl-redirection-but-dont-follow you shouldn't set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`