# PHP curl use header value on next 302 redirect url visit

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-302

I am trying to use header value on next url visit in php curl function.
example visit https://example.com/page1 its 302 redirect and return new header with new value and this value i am trying to use in if again 302 redirect url

my php code is

```
$header = ["Authorization: Bearer $token"];
$header = ["User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36"];
$data = Curl("https://example.com/page1",$header);


function Curl($url,$head= [],$post=''){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,8);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    if($post):
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post); 
    endif;
    if($head)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
    $page = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $page;   
}
```

Comment: Hey, @Hemang! Have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439040/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-using-curl ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the destination URL using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439040/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-using-curl)