# Get links from redirect

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have json. It's consider information about merchants exactly id, link. But this link go to redirect. Like this:

`http:\/\/partners.webmasterplan.com\/click.asp?ref=593856&site=5051&type=banner&tnb=1`

I need to view all this links and link which will be last in the chain of redirection i should save. What is better way to make it? Technology, or...?
Can you give me some advice? Thx!

I found code can it help me?

```
<?php
$url="http://libero-news.it.feedsportal.com/c/34068/f/618095/s/2e34796f/l/0L0Sliberoquotidiano0Bit0Cnews0C12735670CI0Esaggi0Eper0Ele0Eriforme0Ecostituzionali0EChiaccherano0Ee0Eascoltano0Bhtml/story01.htm";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($a);echo"<br>";
if(preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r)){
 $l = trim($r[1]);
 echo $l;
 }else echo "not working";
 ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the destination URL using cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439040/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-using-curl)

Answer (score 0):

This pages sends no `Location` header. To be sure of this, know that this header is always accompanied with a HTTP redirection code (3xx). Here you have a code 200.

With a JavaScript-disabled browser I haven’t been redirected. This strongly hints at a JavaScript redirection. Unfortunately there is no simple way to detect that, as the page’s JS code is minified, and would require heavy work for a PHP script to analyze it.